# how to deploy reactJS application on Tomcat Server

Tags: java, reactjs, tomcat, deployment

I am new in reactjs, I want to deploy my reactjs application on tomcat server instead of running on react server which is default port is 3000.
I run the npm serve command for running the npm local server but need to access that application using tomcat server.

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 28):

**npm run build** can trigger the build process but it generates code assuming the base url doesnt have any relative path  , but what if i want to deploy to a relative path in my server ??.
So what i mean by relative path is that, I have a simpleapp folder inside my tomcat webapps directory and i want to access my react app from that i.e http://localhost/simpleapp . 
It gets even more  complex if you use react router .

I was getting a blank page but later, I [found Some changes](http://frugalisminds.com/react-js/deploy-react-js-in-tomcat/)  done on react router  and package.json that solved my issue .

So the solutions that i found are :-

1. Mention homepage property in package.json

   "homepage": "https://localhost:8080/simpleapp",
2. For react router we must add basename property .

In above case for app to be deployed on simpleapp relative path

```js
<Router basename={'/simpleapp'}>
  <Route path='/' component={Home} />
  {/* … */}
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in the root folder of your react code.

> npm run build

This generates an optimized production build in a folder called 'build', which basically contains an index.html page, with static JS and CSS files. You can then copy + paste these files into your Tomcat WebContent folder.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build) that might throw some light on this.

Comment: So what about the Server.xml file? Do I have to edit it? I've the webapps folder. Do I create a folder there, copy the build into it, and then configure my server.xml? 
I could use some advisory her.

Comment: No, you don't have to edit your server.xml file. Just paste the files in the build folder into your WebContent file in tomcat and you are good to go.

Comment: How do I know which port it is listening on? Is it just 3000 as used in React?

Comment: Nevermind. My sunday morning brain is fighting against me. Thanks for the tip. Regards

Comment: once you paste the build folder contents in the WebContent folder, run your server and you should be able to access your server at port 8080 (localhost:8080)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first decide on how you are going to build your project using Grunt or webpack. You can also add scripts like `npm run build` in your package json which can trigger the build process. 
The built project can be used in any web server by just placing the built files and including the script in your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Follow step 1 as @Passcode above. And for Step 2 use **'HashRouter'**

```
1) Go to index.js

2) Import HashRouter

Eg-> import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect,HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";

3) If you have 'BrowserRouter' replace it with 'HashRouter'.
```

**More details**

1. https://medium.com/@daniel.hramkov/browserrouter-vs-hashrouter-e8bf1c3824ce
2. [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)